# Posting JSON to Flask view using Requests returns 404

Tags: python, json, flask, python-requests

I want to post JSON data to a Flask view using Requests.  However, I get a 404 when I make the request.  Why isn't my code working?  How do I correctly post JSON data?

```
@app.route('/foo/<foo>', defaults={'foo': 'foo'})
@app.route('/foo/<foo>')
def foo(foo):
    print "here"
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    print data
    k = data.get('k', 20)  
    return jsonify(k=k, foo=foostatus='ok')

import requests
params = {'k': 2}
d = requests.get('http://localhost:9090/foo', params=params)
```

Flask logs a 404 for the request.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Sep/2015 11:26:26] "GET /foo?k=2 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Have you tried json.dumps for params?

Comment: I get a weird error "GET /foo?%7B%k%22:%202%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: See, i had a similar issue, but i didn't use request.get_json(). If you want i can post what i did to get the thing done.

Comment: @VivekAnand: Sure can you post your solution

Comment: this error does not seem weird. It is just showing you the query you make and the server tells you the resource does not exist. Which sounds about right.

Comment: @Fraz - do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Issue a `post` request with JSON data, not a `get` request with query parameters.  The route needs to allow the `POST` method as well.
- The 404 is because you are not going to a pattern matching `/foo/<foo>`.  Change the route with the default to exclude `<foo>`, or go to the correct url.
- You do not need to use `force=True` with `get_json` when the request has the correct mimetype.
- The syntax `foo=foostatus='ok'` in your `jsonify` call is invalid.
- Passing a `status` value is redundant, since a 200 response code implies it.

```
@app.route('/hello', defautls={'name': 'world'}, methods=['POST'])
@app.route('/hello/<name>', methods=['POST'])
def hello(name):
    print(name)  # will be 'world' when going to bare /foo
    data = request.get_json()
    k = data.get('k', 20)
    return jsonify(k=k, status='ok')

requests.post('http://localhost/hello', json={'k': 2})
```